# How to check over which divs mouse is moving using TYPESCRIPT or JAVASCRIPT only?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, mouseevent

I have a div1 on which I applied ondrag which is working i.e on dragging the element the handler is getting called and I am getting the target element as that particular div1.
Now while dragging the div1 over the other divs(eg: 5 divs) is it possible to determine the id’s of other div over which the div1 is dragging .
For eg I have this code :

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.design {
  float: left; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 35px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



  <div style="width: 100px; height: 35px;border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondrag="dragging(event)" draggable="true" id="dragtarget">Drag me!</div>

<div class="design" ></div>


<script>
/* Events fired on the drag target */
function dragStart(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
}

function dragging(event) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The p element is being dragged";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But here I have the restriction that I cannot use drag events on any div apart from the two I have applied however I can use mouseevent
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As there are no code examples, we won't be able to give you code responses that may help you. That said, you can start reading from this link to understand **drop targets** and **collision detection**.

https://javascript.info/mouse-drag-and-drop#potential-drop-targets-droppables

Answer (score 0):

if you want drag and drop fuctionality and to check which div is dragged and on which it is dropped you can use jquery sortable ui plugin . Let us assume i have Ledpipeline page on which i have four pipeline stages sortable10 , sortable 11 , 12 and 13  so i used below code hope this will help you

> 

```html
<ul class="ui-sortable defaultscroll" id="sortable-10">
                                                <li data-LeadID="L1">
                                                    <div class="leadpilinelist">
                                                        <p class="leadpname">John Doe</p>
                                                        <div class="selrdurationbox">
                                                            <span class="selerlead">Seller :</span>
                                                            <span class="slerleadname"></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="selrdurationbox">
                                                            <span class="selerlead">Duration :</span>
                                                            <span class="slerleadname"></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                
                                                
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-ss-12 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 padding0">
                                        <div class="leadpipelinebox ovrflw_hiddn">
                                            <div class="headbox_pipeline">
                                                <h4>Contact Made</h4>
                                                <span id="ContactMadeCount">0</span>
                                                <i class="mdi mdi-contacts"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <ul id="sortable-11" class="ui-sortable defaultscroll">
                                                <li data-LeadID="L2">
                                                    <div class="leadpilinelist">
                                                        <p class="leadpname">John Doe</p>
                                                        <div class="selrdurationbox">
                                                            <span class="selerlead">Seller :</span>
                                                            <span class="slerleadname"></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="selrdurationbox">
                                                            <span class="selerlead">Duration :</span>
                                                            <span class="slerleadname"></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-ss-12 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 padding0">
                                        <div class="leadpipelinebox ovrflw_hiddn">
                                            <div class="headbox_pipeline">
                                                <h4>Meeting Arranged</h4>
                                                <span id="MeetingArrage">0</span>
                                                <i class="mdi mdi-account-multiple"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <ul id="sortable-12" class="ui-sortable defaultscroll">
                                                <li data-LeadID="L3">
                                                    <div class='leadpilinelist'>
                                                        <p class='leadpname'>John Doe</p>
                                                        <div class='selrdurationbox'>
                                                            <span class="selerlead">Seller :</span>
                                                            <span class='slerleadname'></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class='selrdurationbox'>
                                                            <span class='selerlead'>Duration :</span>
                                                            <span class='slerleadname'></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-ss-12 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 padding0">
                                        <div class="leadpipelinebox ovrflw_hiddn">
                                            <div class="headbox_pipeline">
                                                <h4>Proposal Made</h4>
                                                <span id="ProposalCounter">0</span>
                                                <i class="mdi mdi-file"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <ul id="sortable-13" class="ui-sortable defaultscroll">
                                                <li data-LeadID="L4">
                                                    <div class="leadpilinelist">
                                                        <p class="leadpname">John Doe</p>
                                                        <div class="selrdurationbox">
                                                            <span class="selerlead">Seller :</span>
                                                            <span class="slerleadname"></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="selrdurationbox">
                                                            <span class="selerlead">Duration :</span>
                                                            <span class="slerleadname"></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script> 


<script type="text/javascript">
    
        function ChangeStage(SenderDiv, RecieveOnStage, LeadID) {
       
     alert ("DraggedDiv :"+SenderDiv + "RecievedonWhichDiv :" + RecieveOnStage + "AttributeID value dragged div :" +LeadID);            
        }



$(document).ready(function() {
$("#sortable-10").sortable({
            start: function (event, ui) {
                $("span#result").html($("span#result").html()
                   + "<b>start</b><br>");
            },
            receive: function (event, ui) {

                var RecieveFrom = ui.sender.attr("id");
                var DroppedONStage = event.target.id;
                var DroppedEmentID = $(ui.item).attr("data-LeadID");
                ChangeStage(RecieveFrom, DroppedONStage, DroppedEmentID);

            },
            connectWith: ".ui-sortable",
        });

        $("#sortable-11").sortable({
            connectWith: ".ui-sortable",
            start: function (event, ui) {
                $("span#result").html($("span#result").html()
                   + "<b>start</b><br>");
            },
            receive: function (event, ui) {

                var RecieveFrom = ui.sender.attr("id");
                var DroppedONStage = event.target.id;
                var DroppedEmentID = $(ui.item).attr("data-LeadID");
                ChangeStage(RecieveFrom, DroppedONStage, DroppedEmentID);
            },
        });

        $("#sortable-12").sortable({
            connectWith: ".ui-sortable",
            start: function (event, ui) {
                $("span#result").html($("span#result").html()
                   + "<b>start</b><br>");
            },
            receive: function (event, ui) {

                var RecieveFrom = ui.sender.attr("id");
                var DroppedONStage = event.target.id;
                var DroppedEmentID = $(ui.item).attr("data-LeadID");
                ChangeStage(RecieveFrom, DroppedONStage, DroppedEmentID);
            },
        });

        $("#sortable-13").sortable({
            connectWith: ".ui-sortable",
            start: function (event, ui) {
                $("span#result").html($("span#result").html()
                   + "<b>start</b><br>");
            },
            receive: function (event, ui) {

                var RecieveFrom = ui.sender.attr("id");
                var DroppedONStage = event.target.id;
                var DroppedEmentID = $(ui.item).attr("data-LeadID");
                ChangeStage(RecieveFrom, DroppedONStage, DroppedEmentID);
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```